Microsoft fonts as webfonts
We are planning to use the current Microsoft default font "Aptos" on a web page. Is it allowed to self-host a copy of the font files for usage on a webpage?
And if not: Is there an alternative way to use these fonts, e.g. to access a version hosted on their servers using a license key?
I ask because e.g. for Adobe fonts this is not allowed and the fonts must be loaded from their own source.

Microsoft font redistribution FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq

You do not have rights to:

copy fonts from a Windows installation to a web server, a process known as web font “self-hosting”.
convert the font to the formats typically associated with web fonts, such as the WOFF or WOFF2 format.


And a specific page for Aptos confirms that the general terms apply: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/aptos#licensing-and-redistribution-info
So that's a no.
Following Microsoft's pointer to fonts.com I arrived at https://www.myfonts.com/collections/aptos-font-microsoft-corporation which offers a license/subscription for the font including use as a web font. Slogging through the licensing details left as exercise for the reader.
